# Bad function evaluation

Tags: function-construction

I am having some trouble with this function

```
Subscript[f, \[Pi]] = {0.0924, 0.00025};
Pade[x_, n_, m_] :=Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^i, {i, 0, n}]/(
1 + Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^(i - n), {i, n + 1, n + m}]) /. 
Subscript[a, n + m] -> Subscript[a, n]/(2 Subscript[f, \[Pi]][[1]])
```

Then, this function works ok but all x values but 0, which gives back

```
In[226]:= Pade[0, 0, 1]
During evaluation of In[226]:= Power::indet: Indeterminate expression 0^0  encountered. >>
Out[226]= Indeterminate
```

However it works ok if I do

```
In[228]:= Pade[x, 0, 1] /. x -> 0
Out[228]= Subscript[a, 0]
```

Any idea why is this?
Indeed the kind of indetermination, 0^0 it's freaking me out, theres no such a power law in my function definition, so I don't have a clue of why is this happening ...

Comment: Don't you have `x=0, i=0` in the numerator ?

Comment: No, the denominator goes as 1 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + ...

Comment: Hey…`Subscript[a, i]*(x)^i` apparently contains `0^0` when `x=0, i=0`.

Comment: In the numerator the sum on `i` starts at 0.

Comment: I just found out what's the problem, the problem is that in the numerator I have
    Subscript[a,0]x^0
This leads to 0^0 ...
When you tell Mathematica to take the limit
    Limit[Pade[x,0,1],x->0]
it performs ok ... now I jast took the 
    Subscript[a,0]
parameter outsude the sum and works fine, however I wonder whether I could do it other way ...

Comment: @zzczd
Thanks for the comment! I just realized ...
I think this would be answered and closed

Thanks all!

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thank you too ;)

Comment: If you believe this question is settled, you could write your own answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was disconnected for some days ...
Yes, it's quite simple, since the problem was the evaluation at x=0, which for the term x^0 gives 0^0, I just avoided writing such a term and did this way" 
`Subscript[f, \[Pi]] = {0.0924, 0.00025};
Pade[x_, n_, m_] :=[Subscript[a, 0] + Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^i, {i, 1, n}]/(
1 + Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^(i - n), {i, n + 1, n + m}]) /. 
Subscript[a, n + m] -> Subscript[a, n]/(2 Subscript[f, \[Pi]][[1]])`

So is just removing the `Subscript[a,0]` term outside the sum

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem was the evaluation at x=0 - which for the term x^0 gave 0^0 - by taking the term out of the summation the wanted result was obtained:

```
Subscript[f, \[Pi]] = {0.0924, 0.00025}; 
Pade[x_, n_, m_] := 
 Subscript[a, 0] + 
   Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^i, {i, 1, n}]/(1 + 
      Sum[Subscript[a, i]*(x)^(i - n), {i, n + 1, n + m}]) /. 
  Subscript[a, n + m] -> Subscript[a, n]/(2 Subscript[f, \[Pi]][[1]])
```

now

```
Pade[0, 0, 1]

(*Subscript[a, 0]*)
```